# OCaml nested recursion

Tags: ocaml

I've been trying to learn OCaml and have manage to get this code to work but was looking for feedback as I don't think its written as nicely as it could be.

```
let table maximum = 
  let rec loop_a maximum acc_a = 
    if acc_a <= maximum then
      let rec loop_b acc_a acc_b = 
        if acc_b <= maximum then 
          begin
            print_string (string_of_int (acc_a * acc_b) ^ "\t");
            loop_b acc_a (acc_b + 1)
          end
        else
          print_newline ()
      in 
      loop_b acc_a 1;
      loop_a maximum (acc_a + 1) 
  in 
  loop_a maximum 1
```

Comment: One suggestion: `print_string (string_of_int (acc_a * acc_b) ^ "\t")` could be: `Printf.printf "%d\t" (acc_a * acc_b)`

Comment: But... what is your code meant to _do_? Are there specific questions you have about it?  If it works but you want to improve it, you may get better feedback at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thanks Chris, didn't even know about the code review site will give it a try. Ive only been looking at Ocaml for a few hours and just wanted to check my first efforts didn't contain anything too offensive to the Ocaml community. A little off topic but do you know anywhere I may look for a UK based tutor for beginner level Ocaml?

Comment: Pay for my relocation to the UK and cover my expenses for a few years and I'll do some research on that for you. ;)

Comment: Re: codereview.stackexchange.com, it seems that no one answers [the (very scarce) OCaml-related review requests](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ocaml). Ian, you’re not the only one who is unaware of that site. ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might suggest you write a very simple function I'm calling `loop_from_to`.

```
let rec loop_from_to m n f =
  if m <= n then (
    f m;
    loop_from_to (m + 1) n f)
```

It takes a starting number, and an end number, and iterates across that range. It takes a function to call on each number in turn.

You then need merely nest these to get the same results as your code.

```
utop # 
loop_from_to 0 8 (fun i ->
  loop_from_to 1 9 (fun j ->
    Printf.printf "%d\t" (i * 9 + j));
  print_newline ()) ;;
1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   
10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  
19  20  21  22  23  24  25  26  27  
28  29  30  31  32  33  34  35  36  
37  38  39  40  41  42  43  44  45  
46  47  48  49  50  51  52  53  54  
55  56  57  58  59  60  61  62  63  
64  65  66  67  68  69  70  71  72  
73  74  75  76  77  78  79  80  81  
- : unit = ()
```

Or to wrap this in a `table` function:

```
let table n = 
  loop_from_to 0 (n-1) (fun i ->
    loop_from_to 1 n (fun j ->
      Printf.printf "%d\t" (i * n + j));
    print_newline ())
```

Comment: Thanks Chris, I dont seem to be able to give you any points, but thanks anyway. It certainly is a terser and easier to see what's going on.